# how to update db on midnight everyday on rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a job to update some information in db every midnight ,so i want to find a way can use rails model to update information to db,

what's the common soluation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cron job which then runs a rake task. Define the task like this in _lib/tasks/your_thing.rake_:

```
task :your_thing => :environment do
  # do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Delayed Job https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job

Answer (score 0):

**Resque https://github.com/blog/542-introducing-resque**